# c++ duplicate function name using ncurses library

Tags: c++, namespaces, ncurses

I'm implementing Tetris game using ncurses library.
I was trying to implementing key handler class and it has member functions named timeout and getch.

key_handler.h

```
#ifndef KEY_HANDLER_H_
#define KEY_HANDLER_H_

#include "tetris.h"
#include <ncurses.h>

namespace tetris {
  class KeyHandler {
    public:
      KeyHandler();
      ~KeyHandler();
      void timeout(int timeout_ms);
      int getch();
    private:
      WINDOW *window_;
      int timeout_ms_;
  };
}
#endif
```

key_handler.cpp

```
#include "key_handler.h"

using tetris::KeyHandler;

KeyHandler::KeyHandler() {
  window_ = newwin(0, 0, 0, 0);
  timeout_ms_ = 1000; // ms
  curs_set(0);
  cbreak();
  noecho();
  keypad(window_, TRUE);
}

KeyHandler::~KeyHandler() {
  delwin(window_);
}

void KeyHandler::timeout(int timeout_ms) {
  timeout_ms_ = timeout_ms;
}

int KeyHandler::getch() {
  wtimeout(window_, timeout_ms_);
  int ch = wgetch(window_);
  return ch;
}
```

When I complie using g++ it said:

```
$ g++ -c key_handler.cpp
In file included from key_handler.cpp:1:
key_handler.h:12: error: ‘stdscr’ is not a type
key_handler.h:13: error: ‘stdscr’ is not a type
key_handler.cpp:19: error: variable or field ‘wtimeout’ declared void
key_handler.cpp:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
key_handler.cpp:23: error: ‘int tetris::KeyHandler::wgetch’ is not a static member of ‘class tetris::KeyHandler’
key_handler.cpp:23: error: invalid conversion from ‘WINDOW*’ to ‘int’
key_handler.cpp:23: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
$
```

Actually there are timeout and getch in ncurses library.
But I thought that they are in different namespace it would be ok.
When I use other names such as timeoutff and getchff g++ compiles successfully.
I think compling fails because of duplicate function name.
I don't want change my function name.
What should I do? And why does this happen? I don't understand. Is this related to ncurses libary or is it general problem for C++ even when using STL?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't spot any error related to your class' function names. Maybe `getch()` and `timeout()` are defined as macros in the included stuff and collide with your function names.

Comment: @g-makulik Ahhhhhhh. Thank you! It makes sense. It was macro. That's why there are 'stdscr' in error messages.

Comment: Accept the answer, he's right ...

Answer (score 4):

timeout and getch are defined as macros in ncurses.h

```
#define timeout(delay)          wtimeout(stdscr,delay)
#define getch()                 wgetch(stdscr)
```

So the preprocessor is replacing your functions before getting round to actual c++ compilation.

Comment: Yes. It is macro.. Thank you for your answer!